# How to allocate dataset in a number of equivalent groups in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a dataset of 1500 observations, with two variables: age and loan amount.
I need to distribute this observations in 10 groups with equal number of observations, where mean of age and mean of loan amount will be the same in each group.

Cannot find what procedure could help me with it :(

Can anybody give me search direction?

Comment: You can use proc surveyselect under the assumption that a random sample is representative of the population. If you need the means to match exactly thats a different story.

Comment: @Reeza Is it possible to have `proc surveyselect` split an input dataset into *disjoint* subsets, as (seemingly) requested here? I don't know of any easy way of doing that.

Comment: @user667489 I missed that, not sure it could be done actually.

Comment: @Reeza It is impossible to match _exactly_, due to continuous range of loan_amount variable.
Now I making it manually: Sort by loan_amount, then assigning Group_number in order Up-Down (e.g. 1-2-3-3-2-1-1-2-3-3-2-1 and so on) as the first approximation, then swap group numbers between pair of observations, watching on mean values for each group and trying to make them as closest to the mean of the whole pool, as possible.

Comment: The method of @user667489 can be used, but it's truly random :)
If initial sampling contains values with large deviations, it demands to balance largest of them with a number of smallest (e.g. 10+1+1 = 3+4+5)
Nevertheless, I gratefully accept any help that you give me :)

Comment: I suggest you repeat my approach with different random seeds each time until you get some deciles that are sufficiently evenly distributed. With only 1500 obs you should easily be able to run this a few thousand times.

Comment: If you have an idea for a more complex algorithm, first have a go at implementing it yourself, and then post a separate question if you get stuck, showing what you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest option I can think of would be to generate a random variable and then use `proc rank` to split your dataset into 10 disjoint subsets with approximately equal mean age and loan amount.

E.g.

```
data temp / view = temp;
  set yourdata;
  call streaminit(1); /*Set seed value for PRNG*/
  random_factor = rand('uniform');
run;

proc rank data = temp out = want groups = 10;
  var random_factor;
run;

/*Sort so that you can use by-group processing in subsequent analysis*/
proc sort data = want;
  by random_factor;
run;
```